# Visual Studio freezes when editing project.json

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Sometimes when I edit project.json files in my .NET Core projects, Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) freezes for 30-60 seconds:

[image: Frozen]

This seems to happen mostly when I edit the `dependencies` section. It seems like it's hanging trying to pull up NuGet IntelliSense, but I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Twitter post](https://twitter.com/zhuravlik26/status/748214609044246528) and some [discussion on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/519#issuecomment-229556479), this was a bug in ReSharper. It's fixed in R# 2016.2 EAP 5 and later.